# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Having some trouble hosting my bot on Heroku

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to host my bot on Heroku, (followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/BPvg9bndP1U). Everything *appears* to be fine, but it does not work. The bot does not come online. Here are the logs if it helps: [image]

Not quite sure what's wrong. I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have done `echo>Procfile` or something of the sort. Either way, it seems that your Procfile contains `ECHO is on.`; instead, it should be in the form `dyno_name: python bot.py`.

Comment: Oh okay, that's probably it. So I change the Procfile to `dyno_name: python bot.py`. Do I still do `echo>Procfile`?

Comment: I said it was in that **format**, I never said that must be *exactly* what you put in the Procfile. You should change `dyno_name` to the name the dyno should have, and `bot.py` to the name of your bot file. And no; never do `echo>...` of any sort; this will just set `...` (whatever you put there) to contain `ECHO is on.`

Comment: You're welcome! :) Also, for future reference, I'm pretty sure the reason the tutorial told you to `echo>Procfile` is to just create the Procfile, containing the text `ECHO is on.`. However you still have to edit the Procfile to have the correct contents.